# Javascript - get value from Flash

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I have html page with an embedded flash. The flash sends me a javascript function with the selected content, namely: currency(eur) or currency(gbp). How can I catch this value with a JS function and send a variable, a string whatever to my html page?Ex: if eur, default, '' otherwise?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds doable, but not exactly clear on what you are asking. How does the `currency` function work? Example?

Comment: I've used firebug and when I press EUR button in the flash, I get this: javascript:%20currency(eur); Break on error: currency is not defined.

Comment: The button is likely a regular html button, rather than a button created in flash. If you "inspect" the button usig Firebug, you will probably see it's href set to "javascript:currency(eur). If the `currency` function isn't defined, you need to find out why. It is defined or alluded to anywhere in the page?

Comment: @user823148, did my solution solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible to connect JS and Actionscript but not easy. I used an iframe to post requests to Actionscript and then get results handed back via url changes.

Answer (score 0):

See this tutorial: http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashjscommand/.

It demonstrates that you can easily do what you're asking. It also has code and a working example.